# Django access to product total price through order model

Tags: python, django, backend, django-class-based-views

I want to get each product's total price in all orders which I mean how much each product sold in all orders. What Query should I write in views.py to display this matter in html?

this is my models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Shipping', 'Shipping'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )
    # order will remain after customer deleted
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

and this is my views.py:

```
def home(request):
    products =  Product.objects.all()
    orders =  Order.objects.all()
    total_order_prices = Order.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))


    orders.products = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('price'))
    context = {'orders':orders, 'products':products,'total_order_prices': total_order_prices  }
    return render(request, 'account/home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Morez!

What I recommend is defining a foreign key to `Order()` in the `Product()`. Doing so would allow you to get related objects much more easily, as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/).

All you would have to do is `products = order.product_set`.

Hope it helps!